# How to parse a tree from a string in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, tree, text-parsing, parse-tree

I have formatted all my university notes as follows:

```
CourseName: {
    Part 1: {
        I.I - Intro: {
            Topic1: {
                descr1;
                descr2: {
                    2.a;
                    2.b;
                    2.c.
                };
                descr3.
            };
            Topic2: {
                descr: {
                    example.
                }.
            }.
        };
        I.II - NextChapter: {
            Topic3: {
                whatever.
            }.
        }.
    };
    Part 2: {
        II.I - FinalChapter: {
            content.
        }.
    }.
}
```

I'd like to *structure them into a **Tree data structure*** and I've tried doing so, both recursively and iteratively, in the past hours, doing many researches online, but none of my attempts at it is working.

I've already implemented a **Node class** (with `self.__value` and a list `self.__children` and all the useful methods you would expect from it) as well as a **Tree class** (with `self.__nodes` as a *dictionary* and other utility methods), so feel free to use methods such as `add_node` or `add_child` in any form of your liking in your answers.

What I'm struggling with is to understand how to structure the function `def parseTree(s, l)` - that ideally takes as inputs a string `s` (my notes) and a list `l` establishing the delimiters i.e. `[":{", ";", "}."]` or `["{","}"]` or similar - and returns a tree object, with each node having as value the text preceding `:{` and a list of children (if any) separated by `;` in the text.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: You should reformat them into a parseable form (JSON, yaml, etc) first.

Comment: chepner and Daniel Roseman are right—it's always easier to use an existing parser. But if you _do_ want to do this yourself, I think what you may be missing is that you're 75% of the way to designing a custom recursive descent parser but haven't hit on the idea of implementing it recursively yet. That may help you search. But, on the other hand, your language is more that simple enough that you could write a simple grammar to feed to a parser generator or parser framework instead of writing code, so you may want to search on that instead.

Comment: @ekhumoro I know I had to show it but I kinda couldn't because it was a not-running mess, result of trial and error and more of a general idea on how to approach the problem rather than actual code

Comment: @abarnert Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was trying to do and looking for. A whole new world just opened up to me! I'm also willing to reformat my "grammar" to make it as simple and parsable as possible for this to work. But 75% of the way it's a long shot... I'm still quite clueless on how to make progress.

Comment: For finishing your existing custom parser, I’m not sure where to point you. (I wouldn’t suggest the textbook I used, even if it didn’t assume you were already solid at manipulating trees recursively in Scheme style but in Common Lisp APIs.) Most recursive descent parser examples are either trivial or ridiculous complicated, because those two extremes are where you use them in practice. But for learning about parser libraries and generators, I know multiple people who learned how to build their first parser via the pyparsing tutorial and wiki full of examples, so that may be worth trying.

Comment: Although Ajax1234’s answer is a pretty good intro example, which also happens to exactly fit your grammar, which makes it a lot easier if you want to figure out how and why it works. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is stored in a file, you can build a simple class to parse the structure into a dictionary. You can recursively traverse the data by creating a new `Notes` object for each key found:

```
file_data = filter(None, [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')])
import re
class Notes:
   def __init__(self, token_data):
     self.token_data = token_data
     self.current_dict = {}
     self.current_vals = []
     self.parse()
   def parse(self):
     while True:
       start = next(self.token_data, None)
       if not start or "}" in start:
         break
       if start.endswith('{'):
          note = Notes(self.token_data)
          final_result = filter(lambda x:x, note.current_vals + [note.current_dict]) if note.current_vals else note.current_dict
          self.current_dict[re.findall('[\w\s\-\.]+', re.sub('^\s+', '', start))[0]] = final_result[0] if isinstance(final_result, list) and len(final_result) == 1 else final_result
          self.token_data = note.token_data
       else:
          self.current_vals.append(re.sub('^\s+', '', start))


course_notes = Notes(iter(file_data)).current_dict
```

Output:

```
{'CourseName': 
    {'Part 1': 
      {'I.I - Intro': 
         {'Topic1': ['descr1;',
                    'descr3.',
             {'descr2': ['2.a;',
                         '2.b;',
                          '2.c.']
                }
               ],
         'Topic2': {'descr': 'example.'}
                 },
                  'I.II - NextChapter': 
               {'Topic3': 'whatever.'}
             },
       'Part 2':{'II.I - FinalChapter': 'content.'}
     } 
   }
```

Comment: This is cool and effective and yes, data is stored in a text file indeed. I just wish I could understand half of the lines of code you've written, haha

Comment: @FlynnRhodes Glad to help! I added more of an explanation in the post, however, all the code does is create a new class for every occurrence of a data key. The file data is store as an iterator, that way, it can be more easily determined when the data source is exhausted.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually almost syntactically valid YAML. A simple substitution will make it valid:

```
data = data.replace(';', ',').replace('.', '')
parsed = yaml.load(data)
```

Comment: You probably want some more specific replacements, at the very least just `;` and `.` that end a line.